# Regex to emulate GitHub autolink references in Markdown

Tags: regex, github, markdown

What would be the regex emulating [GitHub's autolinked references](https://docs.github.com/en/github/writing-on-github/autolinked-references-and-urls)?

It takes Markdown on input and outputs enriched Markdown where strings like `#123` are converted to `[#123](https://github.com/owner/repo/issues/123)`.

These are some examples of the transformations that I'd like the regex to do:

*Input:*

```
1. #123
2. https://github.com/owner/repo/issues/123
3. https://github.com/shoptet/sofa/pull/456
4. owner/repo#123
5. https://github.com/owner/repo/issues/123#issuecomment-123456789
```

*Output:*

```
1. [#123](https://github.com/owner/repo/issues/123)
2. [#123](https://github.com/owner/repo/issues/123)
3. [#123](https://github.com/owner/repo/pull/456)
4. [owner/repo#123](https://github.com/owner/repo/issues/123)
5. [#123 (comment)](https://github.com/owner/repo/issues/123#issuecomment-123456789)
```

I'd prefer one giant regex if possible (I know it's not going to be nice but would allow me to process Markdown in a couple of my favorite editors directly).

Comment: I don't think you can do this with a single regex, unless your editor supports conditional replacements. AFAIK, notepad++ supports this since it uses Boost regex libraries. Which editor are you using?

Comment: By the way, how do you expect to know the user name and repository name with a single `#123`, like in the first case? I don't think hardcoding `owner/repo` would be very useful...

Comment: Yes the repo would be hardocoded in my case; I only do this for a single repo so hardcoding would be fine for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't mind changing the format a little (using `[#123-comment]` instead of `[#123 (comment)]` for comments), you may use this:

```
(?:(owner/repo)?#(\d+)\b|https?://github\.com/([^/]+/[^/]+/(?:issues|pull))/(\d+)(#issue(comment)(-)\d+)?)
```

Replace by: `[\1#\2\4\7\6](https://github.com/owner/repo/issues/\2\4\5)`

You have a demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/kmgyg9/2/).

Answer (score 0):

I'd still prefer a (complex) regex but if anyone is looking for the same post-processing like me, this package can solve it in a Node.js script:

https://github.com/remarkjs/remark-github